# Formal definition of an observer in terms of differentiable manifolds and its mathematical structures

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, observers

I am having difficulty formalizing the root mathematical notions of general relativity, such as spacetime, observer, changes of coordinates, and symmetry groups. I would like to use the language applied in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold

"Spacetime" is a 4D differentiable manifold of events, $\mathcal{M}$. To describe events, I map an open set $U \subset \mathcal{M}$ into flat $\mathbb{R}^4$ using the chart $\psi: U \to \mathbb{R}^4$. This chart is used by a particular observer. If that observer wants to change from say Cartesian to spherical-polar coordinates, they use another chart $\phi$ and, if they want, can overlay the new coordinate curves on their original $\mathbb{R}^4$ or just correspond two 4-tuples using $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ and its inverse. Therefore, the collection of all inertial observers is not one-to-one with the collection of all available charts on $U$, which arrange the events of $U$ onto $\mathbb{R}^4$ in somewhat arbitrary ways, while preserving topological properties such as connectedness and continuity of events.

To define an observer, it seems like it is necessary to associate with the base event $p \in U$ (for which $U$ is the neighborhood) the collection of trajectories $\{ \gamma_i(t) \}$ with varying speeds and directions coursing through $p$. Then, an (instantaneously inertial) observer is defined as a particular element of this set, possessing a speed and direction. Now, for a given observer $\gamma_i$, we construct a chart which is $\mathit{constrained}$ to map the events contained by $\gamma_i$ to the time axis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

So the set of all charts on $U$ available to inertial observers are partitioned into time-axis preserving equivalence classes for each $\gamma_i$, where events along the tangent direction of $\gamma$ are mapped to the time axis of $\mathbb{R}^4$. A composition of charts within a partitioned class is then defined as a change of coordinates applied by a single observer. A composition of charts between the partitions amounts to a visualization or relation of events between inertial observers. If both observers are using Cartesian coordinates, then the composite charts are related by a Lorentz transformation, a symmetry group preserving various quantities defined on $\mathcal{M}$ but computed using numbers in some observer's ${\mathbb{R}^4}$.

Questions: 1) Is there a strict way of partitioning the coordinate charts using these concepts to get at the pure mathematical definition of an "observer"? 2) Is it necessary to define a base event $p$ in order to characterize a set of observers? 3) Can we broaden the definition of the trajectory $\gamma_i$ to not only include a speed but also an acceleration, so that there is a further partition, inclusive of even more charts?

Comment: An observer is a curve in the frame bundle over space time, i.e. an association of an orthonormal basis in the tangent space to each point where the curve passes by. Is this definition not physically motivated?

Comment: This seems way overtechnical. The worldline of an  observer is any timelike causal curve.

Comment: @mikestone So an "observer" is in fact identified as a curve in the spacetime manifold? i.e., not as a chart? Would you say an observer is at liberty to use any coordinate system they want to generate a spacetime diagram?

Comment: They would naturally chose a Minkowski reference frame at each time, with the time axis parallel to the tangent of the curve, but any coordinate system will work..